# Geo Nodes - Raycast from individual Mesh islands

Tags: mesh, geometry-nodes, snapping

I try to create a Node Setup with which I can make several unconnected Planes (contained in one Object) snap to an underlying Groundplane without the Planes beeing rotated (Pic01).
[image]

With my current Setup I can only make the Planes snap to the Groundplane completely, like with a Shrinkwrap Modifier (Pic02).
[image]

Maybe there´s a way to separate each Island, kind of give them individual Origins from which the Raycast shoots down and then I snap the Plane to this Position?

Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve this goal, you would actually only have to use the node `Raycast` in relation to the domain *Face*, instead of the domain *Point*.

Since `Set Position` modifies the individual points of a geometry, working in the attribute domain *Point*, you simply capture the values with `Capture Attribute` in the domain *Face* and then transfer these values.

Like this:

[image]

Here is another alternative that uses an offset instead of resetting the position:

[image]

[image]
<sub>*(Blender 3.2+)*</sub>

Comment: Awesome, thank you so much! :)